# How to add an array to the member of array in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

for example, we have a swift 3 code piece:

first array `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` and second `[5, 6]`

Which function I should to use to add second at first array like:

```
[[[1, 2], [5, 6]], [[3, 4], [5, 6]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can alter an array in that way because new array's type which is `[[Int]]` will be different than old one's `[Int]`.

You can use `map` to do that:

```
let array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

let newArray = array.map { inner in
  return [inner, [5, 6]]
}
```

Less verbose but more compact version: *(thanks to Honey)*

```
let newArray = array.map { [$0, [5,6]] }
```

If you want to update in-place no matter what, downcast your array to `[Any]`:

```
var array: [Any] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

for (index, inner) in array.enumerated() {
  array[index] = [inner, [5, 6]]
}
```

which is not ideal as you have to cast to `Int` or `[Int]` every time you want to access integers in the lists:

```
for inner in array {
  if let inner = inner as? [Int] {
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: result Array from first answer is empty :(

Comment: I don't think you copied my code right. It produced `[[[1, 2], [5, 6]], [[3, 4], [5, 6]]]` in my playground.

Comment: @AlekSzczęsnowicz you could also use a more short version `let newArray = array.map { [$0, [5,6]]}` where `$0` is an element of *array*, ie its first element is `[1,2]` then its second is `[3,4]`. You don't need to write `inner in` because the compiler is smart enough to know there is a parameter and also doesn't care of its name. if there were two parameters then you would have `$0` & `$1`. Also the closure is smart enough to know that you are returning something so you also don't need to specify that. Swift is super swift!